# A very simple if...else statement produces unexpected results

Tags: r

I created a very simple if...else statement in RStudio and I encountered the following issue. I would greatly appreciate if you could take some time to have a look at this:-

(A) Codes:-

```
testing <- function(var1) {
    if(var1 == "heart attack") {
        col_no <- 11
        col_no
    } else if(var1 == "heart failure") {
        col_no <- 17
        col_no
    } else if(var1 == "pneumonia") {
        col_no <- 23
        col_no
    } else {"error"}
}
```

(B) Output:-

```
testing("heart attack")
# [1] 11

col_no
# Error: object 'col_no' not found

testing("heart failure")
# [1] 17

col_no
# Error: object 'col_no' not found

testing("pneumonia")
# [1] 23

col_no
# Error: object 'col_no' not found
```

When I typed in "testing("heart failure")", I was expecting the value of col_no to be 17 instead of an error.

Similarly, when I typed in "testing("pneumonia")", I was expecting the value of col_no to be 23 instead of an error.

Please help!

Comment: The object `col_no` is only local to the function `testing()`. Please read about scoping in R. You have to call the function like: `col_no <- testing("heart attack")`

Comment: Put in `col_no <<- 11` to assign function object into the user environment.

Comment: @AdamQuek no don't do that, just assign the result: `col_no <- testing(...)`

Comment: `library(fortunes); fortune(174)`

Comment: @jogo AdamQuek Cath, Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cleaner syntax using `switch`:

```
testing <- function(var1){
  switch(var1, 
         "heart attack" = 11,
         "heart failure"= 17,
         "pneumonia" = 23,
         "error")
}
```

Calling the function:

```
col_no <- testing("heart attack")
col_no
#[1] 11
col_no <- testing("heart failure")
col_no
#[1] 17
col_no <- testing("pneumonia")
col_no
#[1] 23
col_no <- testing("flue")
col_no
#[1] "error"
```

Comment: ... and now you have to call the function like `col_no <- testing(...)` And this is one possible  good solution without changing the code from OP.

Comment: This is great! I learnt a new function. =)

Answer (score -3):

Because you defined a function (testing), the variable col_no is only available within this function and not in the global environment. Try this instead, then the variable is also defined in the global environment:

```
testing <- function(var1) {
if(var1 == "heart attack") {
    col_no <<- 11
    col_no
} else if(var1 == "heart failure") {
    col_no <<- 17
    col_no
} else if(var1 == "pneumonia") {
    col_no <<- 23
    col_no
} else {"error"}
}
```

Comment: it is quite unwise to do global assignement inside a function. Best is to just assign the return of the function

Comment: Wise or unwise... Depends on the context. Generally replacing return() by <<- is probably a bad idea.

Comment: I'd love to know an example where it is wise, till then, I'll consider this always unwise. Quoting Bill Venables, citation from `fortune(174)`: *"I wish <<- had never been invented, as it makes an esoteric and dangerous feature of the language **seem** normal and reasonable. If you want to dumb down R/S into a macro language, this is the operator for you."*

Comment: I used it for counting the number of times a function is called. When automatically numbering figures in Markdowns, you are able to reduce the code in the caption to a single function call. **However, that was like 2 years ago** - by now there may be better options for automatically numbering figure captions in markdowns.

Comment: @Cath Would you mind explaining why is it unwise to do global assignment inside a function? Thanks!

Comment: @HanZhong for example if running the function replaces a variable in the global environment (you have variable `myvar` but inside function, there is a global assignment of `myvar` to a very different value)

Comment: @HanZhong http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf Circle 6

Comment: "...it is expected in R that a function has no side effects." Will keep this in mind. Thanks again!